# Should we avoid partitionBy when writing files to S3 in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, parquet

The parquet location is:

```
s3://mybucket/ref_id/date/camera_id/parquet-file
```

Let's say I have `ref_id` x3, `date` x 4, `camera_id` x 500, if I write parquet like below(use `partitionBy`), I will get `3x4x500=6000` files uploaded to S3. It is extremely slower than that just wrote a couple of files to the top-level bucket(no multiple level prefix)

What is the best practice? My colleague argues that `partitionBy` is good thing when used together with Hive metastore/table

```
df.write.mode("overwrite")\
  .partitionBy('ref_id','date','camera_id')\
  .parquet('s3a://mybucket/tmp/test_data')
```

Comment: Had once this problem and ended up by fixing max number of partitions to 2... If you're using EMR you can write first to local HDFS then copy data to S3. Try also to set  `spark.hadooop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version=2` to improve performance.

Comment: @blackbishop commit version=2 already applied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem is too many files, which seems to be the case, you need to repartition your RDD/dataframe before you write it. Each RDD/Dataframe partition will generate 1 file per folder.

```
df.repartition(1)\
 .write.mode("overwrite")\
 .partitionBy('ref_id','date','camera_id')\
 .parquet('s3a://mybucket/tmp/test_data')
```

As alternative to `repartition` you can also use `coalesce`.

---

If (after repartition to 1) **the files are too small you**, need to reduce the directory structure. The parquet documentation recommends file size between 500Mb and 1Gb.

https://parquet.apache.org/documentation/latest/

> We recommend large row groups (512MB - 1GB). Since an entire row
>   group might need to be read, we want it to completely fit on one HDFS
>   block.

If your files are a few Kb or Mb then you have a serious problem, it will seriously hurt performance.

Comment: even 1 file per folder is still too many( 3x4x500=6000 files), I mean, don't use the multiple level/prefix ?

Comment: if 1 file per folder is too many, then you have too many folders. each `partitionBy` will generate a folder level. If the files are too small, then you have less folders because it hurt performance.

Comment: @thebluephantom it will depend on the size of your data. It seems on his case, even with 1 file per folder he still ends with very small files